# Facebook login - no redirect after login

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

I'm implementing the facebook login button, and after successful login, there is no redirect, I'm trying to redirect to the same page, and the page doesn't reload.

My skeleton code (doesn't run any function here, I'm just interested in the redirect):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=881911462250499&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {



 FB.init({
      appId      : 'my id',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : 'v6.0'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

                   FB.api('/me', { locale: 'tr_TR', fields: 'email,name' }, function (response) {

                    });
});

}
</script>
```

I did set the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs here on Facebook Developers here:

[image]

When I refresh the page manually after successful login, I can see that I'm logged in and I have a token. It just seems to not redirect when I click the button and log in. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth redirect URLs will be called when you're [manually buliding a login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/).

> The easiest and quickest way to implement Facebook Login is with our official SDKs for JavaScript, iOS, and Android. We recommend you follow our separate guides for these platforms.
>
> However, if you need to implement browser-based login for an app **without using our SDKs**, such as in a webview for a native desktop app (for example Windows 8), or a login flow using entirely server-side code, you can build a **Login flow for yourself by using browser redirects**.

If you're using a FB login button with Javascript SDK, [callback function will be called instead](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#checklogin).

> The first step when your webpage loads is determining if a person is already logged into your webpage with Facebook Login. A call to FB.getLoginStatus starts a call to Facebook to get the login status. **Facebook then calls your callback function with the results.**

If you're going to work with FB login button you can do as the following:

**javascript**

```
FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        const uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        const accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api('/me', { locale: 'tr_TR', fields: 'email,name' }, response => {
            // if you're using jQuery
            $.post(
                "https://your.server/loginEndpoint",
                {
                    provider: 'facebook',
                    uid,
                    accessToken,
                    email,
                    // name
                }, response => {
                    if (response.success) {
                        location.href = "https://your.site/landing-page"
                    }
                }
            )
            // if you using Axios
            Axios.post("https://your.server/loginEndpoint", {
                    provider: 'facebook',
                    uid,
                    accessToken,
                    email,
                    // name
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.success) {
                    location.href = "https://your.site/landing-page"
                }
            });
        });
    }
})
```

**server-side (pseudo code)**

```
provider = request.provider
uid = request.uid
email = request.email
user = db.findBySocialID(provider, uid, email /* or not */)

if (user) {
    login(user)
    response.send(success: true)
} else {
    response.send(success: false)
}
```

## UPDATED: IMPORTANT

The above approach is really vulnerable for impersonation attack. DO NOT
trust any FB uid from client side in server. (If you're going to make people sign in and sign up with their facebook uid)

See how google is [warning about](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) [this problem](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth):

> Important: Do not use the Google IDs returned by getId() or the user's profile information to communicate the currently signed in user to your backend server. Instead, send ID tokens, which can be securely validated on the server.

> Warning: Do not accept plain user IDs, such as those you can get with the GoogleUser.getId() method, on your backend server. A modified client application can send arbitrary user IDs to your server to impersonate users, so you must instead use verifiable ID tokens to securely get the user IDs of signed-in users on the server side.

While [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/accesstokens#confirm) seems not to care about it that much (kinda misleading guide):

> Apps normally need to confirm that the response from the Login dialog was made from the same person who started it. If you're using Facebook's JavaScript SDK it automatically performs these checks so nothing is required, assuming that you're only making calls from the browser.
>
> If you decide to send it back to the server, you should make sure you reverify the access token once it gets to the server. Reverifying the token is covered in our documentation on manually building login flows. You'll need to verify that the app_id and user_id match what you expected from the access token debug endpoint.

You need to use `accessToken` acquired from facebook sdk and validate facebook user again in backend.

**client-side**

```js
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        sendRequestToServer({
            accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken,
            expiresIn: response.authResponse.expiresIn,
            // You can use this but never trust it!
            userId: response.authResponse.userId
        });
    }
});
```

**server-side(pseudo-code)**

```
access_token = req.accessToken
user_id = req.userId
// [GET] https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?access_token={access_token}
fb_user = get_user_info_from_fbgraphql(user_id, access_token)
if (fb_user.id === user_id) {
   sign_in_user(fb_user);
} else {
   // handle_auth_error
}
```

For server-side code implementation see this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: Thank you very much I'm trying to follow your guide, but the problem is that FB.getLoginStatus is not being called after a successful login, it is only called when the page is loaded. Are you sure it should be called right when there is a successful login?

Comment: getLoginStatus is used for facebook login status of a user. If you're trying to login users to your app via facebook you should use FB.login instead of FB.getLoginStatus. Check [Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web). And also in my code, the callback of FB.getLoginStatus might not be triggered because the user is not logged in FB. Because of this: `if (response.status === "connected")`

Comment: Thank you @bravemaster but the FB.login seems to initiate the login process, same as the button click, and then once you're logged in, it does serve as a callback. But using the provided Facebook login button, after a successful logging, the FB.login callback is not called. Does it mean that I have to create a custom facebook login button? Thanks

Comment: About the function FB.getLoginStatus not being triggered, of course I checked it without the if statement there, the problem is that these functions are being called regardless of the facebook login button functionality

Comment: You can see the [official full code example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#example). And your async script tag somehow shows your app id.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just refresh the current page using JavaScript if the login was successful. Try:

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would I write it? There is no callback function being called after logging in

Comment: In which function does the logging in actually take place?